# Retrieving comment(s) on an article - Conduit Project - Thinkster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, conduit

https://thinkster.io/tutorials/node-json-api/adding-comments-to-articles > Section Retrieving comment(s) on an article.

Environment
Thinkster Conduit Project: Angular<->API(node.js)<->MongoDB

- npm(1) (JavaScript):  6.9.0
- mongoose           : ^4.4.10 (Compass Community Version)

**Goal**

Store a comment on a (own written) article and retrieve this comment.

***Note***
To get the local API (for this purpose I used an exact copy of the production ready API supplied by Thinkster on GitHub) working, in particular: posting a comment on an own written article, I had to change in;

1. Model: User.js UserSchema (2x)  >>>  .push(id);  => .concat([id]);
2. Route: routes/api/articles.js router.post('/:article/comments', ...)  >>>  .push(comment);  => .concat([comment]);

These changes had something to do with the drop of 'usePushEach' (versions ago). Nothing is mentioned about it in the current supplied documents on [thinkster](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/node-json-api/adding-comments-to-articles).

The change on the posting route is apparently important: concatenation of comment-objects onto the article when posting a comment, but it works (see pictures).

**Passes**

- Storage of a comment on a own written article (checked and tested
  with Postman & Mongo)
- Remove of the comment (checked and tested with Postman & Mongo)

**Problem!**

Can NOT retrieve, by all means, comment(s) on a own written article (as a list [GET-route]). Somehow the 'comment'-objects are correctly mapped back to the article.
Question: How to solve this? Is this under construction? How to do a callback of the function in which the 'comment' (as argument) has to be mapped back to the article? This argument 'comment' seems to be a empty object, see picture 5: line 356: comment.toJSONFor(user)  ???,

In addition, I noticed, on the conduit client talking to the remote 'production-ready' api, own written articles ar not listed as own feed, however they do appear in de global list.

1) Storage of a comment on a own writer article works fine                                             [image]
2) Mongo Db:
[image]
3) Retrieve (.get) comments by Postman:
[image]
4) Response on the terminal:
[image]
5) Section of the Json:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
The problem occurred by two pitfalls:

1. The promise 'comment' does not get aborted
2. It is not possible to 'push' directly into the 'req.article.comments' array property

**Fixes**

1. In the original code (GitHub) the .catch(next) is fit on the User [Document], this 
   stopper needs to sit on the promise stream 'comment' instead. [image]
2. 'Old fashion' JavaScript is needed to keep track of existing comment ids, load them separately into a new Array and push the new comment id onto it (so far pushing is allowed). Also the very first comment id on a article needs to be stored in an array type variable. [image]
   In both cases a new created array is allowed to map (=) onto the 'req.article.comment'-array property; pushing on it causes an $pushAll error and .concat(...) does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

**...better Solution**

- Circumscribe the sync post-route into an asynchronous post-route
- But keep fix 2[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCFgJ.png)